# Set focus to textbox in ASP.NET Login control on page load

Tags: asp.net, authentication, pageload, setfocus

I am trying to set the focus to the user name TextBox which is inside an ASP.NET Login control.

I have tried to do this a couple of ways but none seem to be working.  The page is loading but not going to the control.

Here is the code I've tried.

```
SetFocus(this.loginForm.FindControl("UserName"));
```

And

```
TextBox tbox = (TextBox)this.loginForm.FindControl("UserName");
if (tbox != null)
{    
  tbox.Focus();
} // if
```

Comment: if you're not sure in success of `FindControl()` don't `cast`. Use operator `as` because otherwise `(TextBox)null` will throw `NullReferenceException`. So your null-check will be never reached.

Comment: Do you have convert your asp.net login control to template ?

Comment: Yes, I have converted the login control to a template.

Comment: Is your login control within an UpdatePanel?

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - No, but it is in a MultiView

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using a ScriptManager on the Page? If so, try the following:

```
public void SetInputFocus()
{
    TextBox tbox = this.loginForm.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox;
    if (tbox != null)
    {
       ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).SetFocus(tbox);
    }
}
```

Update: Never used a multiview before, but try this:

```
protected void MultiView1_ActiveViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SetInputFocus();
}
```

Comment: @Aristos - Thanks for pointing that out, I just copied and pasted my own SetInputFocus method and forgot to change it for this question.

Comment: Still nothing, it is getting to the `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).SetFocus(tbox);` statement but still doesnt set the focus

Comment: @anD666 - Updated my answer, give it a try. Just a guess, so it's untested. I just robbed the idea of a google search result.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the master page.  I tried copying the login control into a clean page and your code worked fine.  Using the master page it doesnt seem to find the form with runat="server".  I think I will remove it from a master page.  Thank you

Comment: The script manager wasnt on the master page, I have tried moving it onto that and it still cannot find a form with the tag runat=server.  This form is on the master page and i cant add another to the webform.

Answer (score 31):

I'm using Page.Form.DefaultFocus and it works:

```
// inside page_load, LoginUser is the Login control
Page.Form.DefaultFocus = LoginUser.FindControl("Username").ClientID;
```

Comment: I agree with @Marcel. This should be the accepted answer. Code worked perfectly, and it is the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetFocus(LoginCntl.FindControl("UserName"));
}
```

Comment: When the page loads, the cursor is positioned in the username textbox. It works out. Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do the following:

-Register two scripts (one to create a function to focus on your texbox when page is displayed, second to register id of the textbox)

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "on_load", 
                "<script>function window_onload() \n { \n if (typeof(idLoginTextBox) == \"undefined\" || idLoginTextBox == null) \n return; \n idLoginTextBox.focus();\n } \n window.onload = window_onload; </script>");

this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Focus", String.Format("<script>var idLoginTextBox=document.getElementById(\"{0}\").focus();</script>", this.loginForm.ClientID));
```

As the result you should get the following in your code:

```
      <script>
          function window_onload()
          {
            if (typeof(idLoginTextBox) == "undefined" || idLoginTextBox == null)
                return;     
            idLoginTextBox.focus();
        }
        window.onload = window_onload;     
      </script>   



<script>
        var idLoginTextBox=document.getElementById("ctl00_LoginTextBox").focus();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this too and I've found a solution that seems to work very well even with deeply nested controls (like AspDotNetStorefront a.k.a. ASPDNSF uses). Note the following code called from the `Page_PreRender` routine. I knew the name of the TextBox I wanted to give focus to and so I just called `FocusNestedControl(Me, "UserName")`. I just used `Me` here because all the routine needs is a parent of the control to get focus; it doesn't matter which parent.

```
    Public Function FocusNestedControl(ByVal ParentControl As Control, ByVal ControlNameToFocus As String) As Control

        If ParentControl.HasControls Then
            For Each childCtrl As Control In ParentControl.Controls
                Dim goodCtrl As Control = FocusNestedControl(childCtrl, ControlNameToFocus)
                If goodCtrl IsNot Nothing Then
                    goodCtrl.Focus()
                    Return goodCtrl
                End If
            Next
        Else
            If ParentControl.ID = ControlNameToFocus Then
                ParentControl.Focus()
                Return ParentControl
            End If
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus directly on LoginControl and it will automatically set focus on first field in control. In your case:

```
this.loginForm.Focus();
```

More info on MSDN: [How to: Set Focus on ASP.NET Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178232.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        Login.FindControl("UserName").Focus();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem arrized when i moved login control to a custom control and tried to find UsernameTextBox at the OnInit() method.
OnInit of a control is executed before OnInit of Page and this is why no Form control have been created.

I moved the call to UsernameTextBox to the OnLoad function and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me, so I simply tried:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // This works for me
    TxtMyTextBoxName.Focus();
}
```

... and it worked!
With an ASP TextBox defined as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtMyTextBoxName" type="search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put your textbox inside this code on  ASP.NET

```
<form id="WHATEVERYOUWANT" runat="server" method="post">
 <div>
  <!-- Put your code here--> 
 </div>
</form>
```