# Set focus on an asp.net control on Page Load

Tags: javascript, pageload, clientscript

I want to set focus on a control when page is loaded.
I wrote this code but not working..

```
protected void setFocus(System.Web.UI.Control ctrl)
    {
        string s = "<SCRIPT language='javascript'>document.getElementById('" + ctrl.ID + "').focus() </SCRIPT>";
        Type csType = this.GetType();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "focus", s);
    }
```

and this line in PageLoad method:

```
this.setFocus(txtHeightfeet);
```

Please help.

EDIT:

This is HTML:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtHeightfeet" type="text" maxlength="2" id="MainContent_txtHeightfeet" class="textEntry2" style="width:65px;" />
```

This is aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHeightfeet" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry2" MaxLength="2" Width="65"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;ft&nbsp;
```

and in code behind cs file, i declared it the same as you have mentioned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set focus to textbox in ASP.NET Login control on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043592/set-focus-to-textbox-in-asp-net-login-control-on-page-load)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just call the [`Focus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178232.aspx) method of the control.

No need for that Javascript.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtHeightfeet.Focus(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup for txtHeightfeet and how you've declared it in the code-behind?

Comment: Can you post the C# declaration of txtHeightfeet?

Comment: in designer.cs: protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtHeightfeet;